# What does the following syntax mean?

Tags: typescript, interface

I see code such as

```
export interface SmartType {
    type: string;
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

can someone explain the what the last line, defining x means?

Comment: `x` is an associative array of type `any`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that a `SmartType` can be indexed with `string`s and values are of type `any`.

```
interface SmartType {
    type: string;
    [x: string]: any;
}

let obj: SmartType = { type: 'Thing' };
obj['test'] = 'Hello World';
obj['test2'] = 10;
console.log(obj);
```

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p5r5u54n/))

The typescript handbook explains this in its section on [Interfaces: Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

Comment: So do TypeScript and ES6 conflict on what the `[ ]` does in an object definition?

Comment: That's incorrect, there's no `x` property in `SmartType`. Object of `SmartType` are associative arrays themselves.

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko I just realized and removed it.

Comment: @zero298 I believe the difference is that there is a type inside the `[ ]` which indicates it's an index definition for the object. If there was not a type it will probably try to dynamically construct the property. I'm not sure, I've never used the brackets to dynamically construct anything.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't define `x`, what it does is it says that objects of `SmartType` can be indexed into with a `string` index, and values stored in those indices are of type `any`:

```
const s: SmartType;
s['foo']; // -> any
```

`x` is just a name, that's there more to give the keys a meaning, I presume. Any other name wouldn't change the meaning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Adding something that is not explicit in other answers. The following TypeScript interface:

```
interface SmartType {
    type: string;
    [x: string]: any;
}
```

Requires the presence of a  key named `type` that only accepts values of type `string`.

Then it specifies that *any* other key ***may*** be `string`s and that they may hold `any` type of value. But *those other keys could also be numeric*.

And the only reason that `type` can hold `string`s is because the `string` type is a subset of the `any` type (the type of the indexer in the `SmartType` interface).

That's why, in addition to the required `type` property, you can add any number of properties holding any type of value in an object of type `SmartType`.

```
const someSmartValue: SmartType = {
    type: 'some text',
    whatever: {},
    anyOtherTextProperty: ['array', 'containing', 'whatever', 1000, true, {a: () => false}],
    2: () => 'OK'
};
```

[Check it on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20SmartType%20%7B%20%20type%3A%20string%3B%20%20[x%3A%20string]%3A%20any%3B%7Dconst%20someSmartValue%3A%20SmartType%20%3D%20%7B%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'some%20text'%2C%20%20%20%20whatever%3A%20%7B%7D%2C%20%20%20%20anyOtherTextProperty%3A%20['array'%2C%20'containing'%2C%20'whatever'%2C%201000%2C%20true%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20false%7D]%2C%20%20%20%202%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20'OK'%7D%3B)

Changing the return value of the indexer to `boolean` would render the definition invalid:

```
interface InvalidType {
    type: string; // [ts] Property 'type' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'boolean'.
    [index: string]: boolean;
}
```

With the `SmartType` interface, the following would also be illegal, because a key named `type` is specifically required:

```
const anotherSmartValue: SmartType = {
    someProp: {}
}; // [ts] Type '{ someProp: {}; }' is not assignable to type 'SmartType'. Property 'type' is missing in type '{ someProp: {}; }'.
```